# Why are some Word Classes not Immediately Dominated by a Phrasal Category?

Tags: syntax-trees

<sub>Source: pp 106-107, *Syntax, A Generative Introduction* (3 ed, 2012) by Andrew Carnie</sub>

> [6.] iv) ***English Phrase Structure Rules***
>   a) CP ⟶ (C) TP
>   b) TP ⟶ {NP/CP} (T) VP
>   c) VP ⟶ (AdvP+) V (NP) ({NP/CP}) (AdvP+) (PP+) (AdvP+)
>   d) NP ⟶ (D) (AdjP+) N (PP+) (CP)
>   e) PP ⟶ P (NP)
>   f) AdjP ⟶ (AdvP) Adj
>   g) AdvP ⟶ (AdvP) Adv
>   h) XP ⟶ XP conj XP
>   i) X ⟶ X conj X

For example, per (d), why can an NP (= Noun Phrase) Immediately Dominate D (= Determiner)? Why is there no Phrasal Category DP (= Determiner Phrase) that intervenes between NP and D?

Comment: The lexical categories have corresponding phrasal categories that are in a sense expansions of them. There is a category called 'determinative phrase' (DP) which as its name implies is headed by a determinative, e.g. "almost every". "not many" etc. We don't call it 'determiner phrase' because 'determiner' is a function not a category.

Comment: You seem to be asking about why some syntacticians have used abbreviatory names  ending in "P".  Who cares?  It's not a linguistic question.

Comment: @BillJ **You** don't call then "determiner phrases" (and thank you for that), but a lot of people do; it's an icon of proper Chomskyan faith. And one is always having to transpose symbols to see what they really intend to say. Labels in rule-governed systems are subject to the same economic forces as sunglass design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question. "Why are some word classes not immediately dominated by a phrasal category" - any word is dominated by some phrasal category. Your question is probably rather about why some words are dominated by a phrase that doesn't have the same category as this word (e.g. D is not dominated by DP).

A node is always immediately dominated by the category that the **head** of this phrase determines. So the nodes in an NP will be dominated by NP because the head of the NP is an N, the nodes in a VP will be dominated by VP because the head of the VP is a V, ...

It seems like in this syntax theory, NPs can also contain (optional) determiners, but whatever else there may be, whether there is also a D, a PP, ..., the head of the phrase is still N, and this is what determines the category of the NP.
I haven't read that book myself; either there is also the notion of DPs that is not shown here or (more probably) all DPs are considered NPs - this is an eternal dispute among syntax theories, some argue that it is more reasonable to assume D is the head of a phrase like "the cat" because, amongst others, the choice of the determiner influences the inflection of the N so one can assume that NP is more like a complement to D that gets selected by it and so on, some prefer to go with the more traditional assumption that the head of such a phrase is still an N and that determiners are additional (if you stick to the assumption that all NPs must eventually go into DPs, you must assume an empty determiner head in a phrase like "I like [ø cats]") so the phrasal category is an NP.

You say "for example, per (d) ...". What else do you mean? I don't see anything more that looks weird.